# Using Zoho API from within a Blazor WASM app

Tags: blazor-webassembly, zoho, asp.net-blazor

Im not having any luck whatsoever trying to get my Blazor WASM (client-side) app to obtain an access token from Zoho API.

I am able to obtain an authorization response which contains an "access_token". Unfortunately this token is not working (i believe this is an authorization code?).

Anybody having any success with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have obtained the access_token then you are part of the way there.

When there are issues after obtaining an access token and attempting to make an API query in a coding language, sometimes trying the API request (with th access_token) using the Curl command line helps to reveal the issue.  Zoho usually includes an example Curl command in the API documentation.

Comment: My question right now is that my app is blazo wasm (totally client side). So it seems that my requesting for an authorization request is the wrong approach (this is for server-based apps only?). Regardless, i was only able to obtain a token/code by requesting an authorization request using response_type = "token". If I specify "code" (as suggested in the zoho documentation) then i receive an error.